# How to get the lowest price from a particular group of users MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-python

I have been at this for a few days without much luck and I am looking for some guidance on how to get the lowest estimate from a particular group of sullpiers and then place it into another table.

I have 4 supplier estimate on every piece of work and all new estimates go into a single table, i am trying to find the lowest 'mid' price from the 4 newsest entries in the 'RECENT QUOTE TABLE' with a group id of '1' and then place that into the 'LOWEST QUOTE TABLE' as seen below.

```
RECENT QUOTE TABLE:
suppid    group    min    mid    high
     1        1    200    400    600
     2        1    300    500    700
     3        1    100    300    500
    [4]      [1]   50    [150]   300
     5        2    1000   3000   5000
     6        2    3000   5000   8000
     7        2    2000   4000   6000
     8        2    1250   3125   5578

LOWEST QUOTE TABLE:
suppid    group    min    mid    high
     4        1    50     150    300
```

Any help on how to structure this would be great as i have been loking for a few days and have not been able to find anything to get me moving again, im using MYSQL and the app is made in Python im open to all suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to select only row with group 1, you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO lowest_quote_table 
    SELECT * FROM recent_quote_table 
    WHERE `group` = 1 
    ORDER BY `mid` ASC 
    LIMIT 1.
```

If you want a row with the lowest mid from every group, you can do something like

```
INSERT INTO lowest_quote_table 
    SELECT rq.* FROM recent_quote_table AS rq 
    JOIN (
        SELECT `group`, MIN(`mid`) AS min_mid FROM recent_quote_table 
        GROUP BY `group`
    ) MQ ON rq.`group` = MQ.`group` AND rq.`mid` = MQ.min_mid
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks, i ended up having to specify the individual fields to not pull the auto incrementing id number over but looking back at my question i never specified that.

Cheers you have saved me a stack of time and head ache :)